# Метод concat(),так же как и метод slice(),не меняет исходный массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы, методы

Вот код.. По заданию:Есть массив строк arr. Создайте массив arrSorted – из тех же элементов, но отсортированный.
Исходный массив не должен меняться. В решении используется метод slice().Я использовал метод concat(). Это верный подход в данном случае,с учётом, что  по условию исходный массив не должен меняться?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Just a Generic Page</title>
<script>


var arr = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "CSS"];
var arrSorted = arr.concat().sort(); 
alert(arrSorted);
alert(arr);
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: да, метод concat создает новый массив

Comment: Спасибо)Вопрос простой конечно, и за такое меня тут периодически пинают, местные гуру)

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl если вас пинают за простые вопросы - зовите модератора

Answer (score 1):

Да, подход вполне соответствует условию: [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) возвращает новый массив, поэтому исходный массив не поменяется при вызове [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Вместо `concat` также можно использовать:

1. [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
2. [spread оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator): `[...array]`
3. [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 0):

Предложу еще свой метод решения:

```
let arr = ["HTML", "JavaScript", "CSS"]; //["HTML", "JavaScript", "CSS"]
let arrSorted = new Array(...arr).sort(); //["CSS", "HTML", "JavaScript"]
```